# Django upvote & downvote system

Tags: python, django, templates, project, social-likes

I am working on a project for my course that users can vote items either up or down. I'm using Django and have just begun learning it recently.

I am having an issue to get past clicking and activating the buttons separately as my downvote button just activates the upvote.

My template:

```
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <strong>
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <form action="{% url 'post_vote' post.slug %}" class="d-inline" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% if liked %}
                                <button type="submit" name="blogpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like"><i 
                                    class="fa-solid fa-circle-up" style="color: #1ea427;"></i></button>
                                {% else %}
                                <button type="submit" name="blogpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like"><i 
                                    class="fa-regular fa-circle-up"></i></button>
                                {% endif %}
                            </form>
                            {% else%}
                            <span class="text-scondary"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-up"></i></span>
                            {% endif %}
                            <span class="text-secondary">{{ post.number_of_up_votes}}</span>
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <strong>
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <form action="{% url 'post_vote' post.slug %}" class="d-inline" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% if disliked %}
                                <button type="submit" name="blogdownpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like"><i 
                                    class="fa-solid fa-circle-down" style="color: #ff0000;"></i></button>
                                {% else %}
                                <button type="submit" name="blogdownpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like"><i 
                                    class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i></button>
                                {% endif %}
                            </form>
                            {% else%}
                            <span class="text-scondary"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i></span>
                            {% endif %}
                            <span class="text-secondary">{{ post.number_of_down_votes}}</span>
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
                        <strong class="text-secondary"><i class="far fa-comments"></i>
                            <!-- Our total_comments variable goes before the closing strong tag -->
                            {{ total_comments }}</strong>
                        {% endwith %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.views import generic, View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Post
from .forms import CommentForm


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6


class PostDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by('created_on')
        liked = False
        disliked = False
        if post.up_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        elif post.down_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            disliked = True

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": False,
                "liked": liked,
                "disliked": disliked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm(),
            },
        )
        
    
    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by('-created_on')
        liked = False
        disliked = False
        if post.up_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        elif post.down_vote.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            disliked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
        
        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": True,
                "liked": liked,
                "disliked": disliked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm(),
            },
        )


class PostVote(View):

    def post(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

        if post.up_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.up_vote.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.up_vote.add(request.user)

        if post.down_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.down_vote.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.down_vote.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug]))
```

My models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="news_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    up_vote = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='news_up_vote', blank=True)
    down_vote = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='news_down_vote', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_up_votes(self):
        return self.up_vote.count()

    def number_of_down_votes(self):
        return self.down_vote.count()
```

I tried to change multiple things as in positioning and wording and watched many videos.

Comment: The issue here is that in your PostVote view call you are not specifying the kind of vote the user performed (upvote or downvote). What ur PostVote View logic is doing is simply toggling the votes whenever the view is called. What this class PostVote(View) is saying essentially is
1. If this person upvoted previously remove that upvote else add a new upvote
2. If this person downvoted previously remove that downvote else add a new down vote

Answer (score 2):

I have updated  the upvote form in your template to include a hidden field to denote the type of vote

```html
<form action="{% url 'post_vote' post.slug %}" class="d-inline" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="vote_type" value="upvote">
    {% if liked %}
    <button type="submit" name="blogpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-up" style="color: #1ea427;"></i>
    </button>
    {% else %}
    <button type="submit" name="blogpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-up"></i>
    </button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

I also updated your downvote form to include a hidden field to denote the type of vote

```html
<form action="{% url 'post_vote' post.slug %}" class="d-inline" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="vote_type" value="downvote">
    {% if disliked %}
    <button type="submit" name="blogdownpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-down" style="color: #ff0000;"></i>
    </button>
    {% else %}
    <button type="submit" name="blogdownpost_id" value="{{post.slug}}" id="btn-like" class="btn-like">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i>
    </button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

I have updated your PostView class to use the value of that hidden fie

```py
class PostVote(View):
    def post(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

        vote_type = request.POST.get('vote_type', None)
        if vote_type == 'upvote':
            # If the person has not up voted previously then we add a new vote
            post.up_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists() is False and post.up_vote.add(request.user)
            
            # If this person previously downvoted this Post then we remove the downvote because because a preson cannot upvote and downvote the same Post
            post.down_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists() and post.down_vote.remove(request.user)

        elif vote_type == 'downvote':
            # If the person has not down voted previously then we add a new vote
            post.down_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists() is False and post.down_vote.add(request.user)

            # If this person previously upvoted this Post then we remove the upvote because because a preson cannot upvote and downvote the same Post
            post.up_vote.filter(id=request.user.id).exists() and post.up_vote.remove(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that has been great help to me!